# How to get Alt+SysRq work on a Dell Latitude E6530?

Tags: shortcut-keys, laptop, dell, reboot, sysrq

I have a Dell Latitude E6530. The keyboard has a <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>). However the magic keys (especially the famous <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) doesn't work.

SysRq is enabled in /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq (I get 1 if I cat this file).
It works from external USB keybord.

How can I have the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (in fact, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) reboot my system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Dell E6420 works as follows

- Press/hold both <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- Press/hold <kbd>Home/Sysrq</kbd>
- Release <kbd>Fn</kbd>
- Press key (tested with <kbd>T</kbd>)

Comment: I realized that in step 3, you can release Fn OR bot Fn and Home/SysRq. Anyway this works on on the 6530 as well.

Comment: how many hands do you need to perform this ? ;-)

Comment: On a Dell Latitude 7300, I can confirm that only `Alt+Fn+R+b` (for reboot) seems to work: https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-Developer-Systems/how-to-generate-SysRq-key-combos-on-Dell-XPS-7390/td-p/7439878

Answer (score 2):

The documentation (`/usr/src/linux*/Documentation/sysrq.txt`) says this:

```
On x86   - You press the key combo 'ALT-SysRq-<command key>'. Note - Some
           keyboards may not have a key labeled 'SysRq'. The 'SysRq' key is
           also known as the 'Print Screen' key. Also some keyboards cannot
           handle so many keys being pressed at the same time, so you might
           have better luck with "press Alt", "press SysRq", "release SysRq",
           "press <command key>", release everything.
```

Comment: It's interesting to know it may be too much keys pressed at the same time, especially since I need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> too. I tried releasing <kdb>SysRq</kbd> before pressing the command, to no avail. I also tested all the combinations with or without <kbd>Fn</kbd>, with <kbd>Home (SysRq)</kbd>, <kbd>End (PrntScrn)</kbd> and others, but none worked.

Comment: I tried plugging an external keybord, and that one works (I'll edit my question to mention this fact).

Comment: Worked for me, the variant with releasing sysrq