# How does Alt+SysRq work on a DellXPS13?

Tags: dell, sysrq

sometimes my laptop freezes and normally I use the "magic SysRQ" combination to reboot it.

How does this work on my [DellXPS13](https://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1/product-support/servicetag/0-bS9MNDRDbUI0REd4YkFFLzBXTC9nQT090/overview) ?

The closest question I could find was this one: [How to get Alt+SysRq work on a Dell Latitude E6530?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168502/how-to-get-altsysrq-work-on-a-dell-latitude-e6530). But no matter which combination I try it does not work.

I am using a German QWERTZ-Keybardlayout but I think that should make no difference for the SysRq key.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question. I've never needed it but try it a couple times a year as a test and it's never worked for me on new or old Dell laptops.

Answer (score 4):

On an XPS 13 9380, first enable the media keys by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.
Afterwards <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> will trigger SysRq.

Another option is to <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> but you'll have to release <kbd>Fn</kbd> to trigger a command key.

Comment: that works. thanks. Indeed, you need to do Fn + Alt + R then release Fn while holding others then press the extra command key.

Comment: thanks @BosonBear that works on my 9343

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the Dell XPS 13 model. For the 7390, the Setup and Specifications" brochure indicates that SysReq is represented by <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. You may try if that works for you, although no indication about SysRq is available in the manual of your model, the 9360.